# Assign Javascript variable to PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I understand...

- the disparity between PHP being server-side and Javascript being client-side.
- AJAX can patch this issue.
- the XMLHttpRequest object is significant.

However, I still can't work out how to pass the variable between the two languages.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks for your replies so far, I should clarify that I would like to do this without loading a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an AJAX request containing the value of the variable in the query string or POST body.

The PHP script at the other end of the URL can read the value from the query string or POST body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What sort of request would this be, and does it require an external PHP file?

Comment: It can be GET or POST.  If it's not idempotent, it should be POST.  It can be any PHP file you want; the PHP file will receive a separate request.

Answer (score 0):

you could use JSON with JS and decode it with php, but as the post above states, it involves ajax.

Comment: This sounds good as I'm already doing something similar with other data on the page. How do I get the two variables I'm interested in to format as JSON? After that I could probably get it working.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Tutorial found at [link](http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/)

You should give a more detailed example of what you want to accomplish. But if I understand correctly, you want to use a value from your JavaScript code in your PHP code?

You should try using POST or GET parameters to pass values into PHP. For PHP to be able to do anything, you will have to load a new page.

Lets say you have `list.php` serving a list of posts. You want to "like" a post. Your JavaScript is on this page. When you click "like", an AJAX POST is sent to `like.php` with POST parameter id=123.

In like.php, you get the value from the request (using `$_POST['id']` or something more appropriate), do your magic (save to db) and echo some result, `json_encode(array('success' => true))` for example.

The JavaScript-code that called `like.php` can then use it's callback to check if the "like" was a success or not and display feedback. The `like.php` could be any page, you could use `list.php` if you'd want. I used `like.php` for clarity.

If this is not at all what you wanted, please provide more information.

Comment: You're right that I want to use a Javascript value in my PHP. My problem lies in that even after having read the documentation for the AJAX POST function, I don't understand all of the parameters and therefore it won't work.

Comment: Read up on jQuery AJAX ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)). Your javascript-code will look something like: 
`$.post("like.php", { id: 123},
   function(data) {
     // check data if everything went well, append some feedback to DOM
   });`

And your like.php something like:

`<?
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
?>`
There are plenty of good tutorials for this, for example: 
[link](http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm trying to pass two JS variables, lat and lng. My code looks like this so far, but the PHP throws an error that the variable is undefined:
`$.post("index.php", { lat: lat, lng: lng}, function(data) { // check data if everything went well, append some feedback to DOM });` and `$lat = $_POST['lat'];
echo json_encode(array('success' => true));`

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't looked at jQuery framework for javaScript, do it.

If you have a variable called `city` in JS, you can pass it to the `file.php` by using

```
var city = "London";
$.get("file.php", {location:city} );
```

Which is a HTTP GET request.

In PHP(file.php), you then grab it by using

```
$city = $_GET['location'];

echo $city; //London
```

Comment: This looks promising, but flags up the PHP error:
**Notice: Undefined index: location**
Any ideas?

Comment: @Sebastian Hard to say, it means that the variable wasn't sent. First make sure the function is run, and then try like location = "London" directly in the function to make sure that the value is set.