# Cakephp master/details add

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have two tables, has-many relationship,
in the master add.ctp, allow user to upload 0~5 files(file path information are stored in details table)

I want to dynamically display attachment(detail) form in the master/add.ctp

1, user choose number of files want to upload from dropdown list,

```
echo $this->Form->input('attachments', array( 'options' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),'empty' => '(choose one)', 'onchange' => 'showNumber(this.value)'));
```

then forloop

```
{
        echo $this->Form->input('attachment_path', array('type'=>'file','label' =>'Attachment, Maximum size: 10M'));    
}
```

//but I don't know how to capture this.value, I know Javascript can not pass value to php.

or user click 'add another attachment' link, then detail form shows up.

How to achieve this function, any help would be appreciated.

I have read this article:
[Assign Javascript variable to PHP with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576656/assign-javascript-variable-to-php-with-ajax)
and get same error: the variable is undefined

Edit:
http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Adding-fields-to-a-form-dynamically-a-complex-case-td3386365.html

> 'For each field use a default name with [] at the end (which will make 
>   it stack like a array) example: data[][book_id] after the fields have 
>   been submitted'

Where should I place the []?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Ajax for this.

Simply create an ajax call on `select.change()` and then a method in the controller that returns the necessary info.

You can return an array of data using `echo json_encode(array('key' => 'value'))` directly on your controller (or better in a custom view) and access it with Javascript:

```
success: function(data) {
     alert(data.key);
}
```

Edit...

In your javascript use something like...

```
$('select').change(function(e) {
    var select = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/attachments/youraction",
        data: { data: { id: select.find(":selected").val() } },
        success: function(data) {
            for (i in data) {
                var input = $('<input>', {type: "file", label: data[i].Attachment.label})
                $('form.your-form').append(input);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Then in "Yourcontroller" create "youraction" method:

```
<?php
class AttachmentsController extends AppController
{
    public function youraction()
    {
        if (!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax() || !$this->RequestHandler->isPost() || empty($this->data['id']))
        {
            $this->cakeError('404');
        }

        // Do your logic with $this->data['id'] as the select value...
        $data = $this->Attachment->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => $this->data['id'])));
        // ....


        // then output it...
        echo json_encode($data);

        // This should be done creating a view, for example one named "json" where you can have there the above echo json_encode($data);
        // Then..
        // $this->set(compact('data'));
        // $this->render('json');
    }
}
```

It's more clear now?? If you have doubts about ajax + cakephp you should do a search on the web, where you will find a lot of tutorials.

Comment: I know very little about ajax... Could you explain it more detail? I tried to do this, but it did not work.<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> var variableToSend = 'foo'; 
$.post('admin_add.ctp', {variable: variableToSend}); </script>

Comment: Ok let me expand my response with a better example

Comment: Elboletaire, thanks for the detailed reply :) 
I'll try it later tomorrow ... Thanks again....

Comment: It would be a good point if you start accepting some of the answers to any of the questions you have created since you registered on stackoverflow

Comment: It didn't work, because attachment can not save without master_id(FK)

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach to achieve this function. (finally got it :）)

http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/foreach_loop_with_save_only_saving_last_member_of_array

Yes, AJAX can do lots of things,  to me, it's very hard to understand the logic in a day..

Anyway, Thanks again.